# How to modify custom wp_query to sort by word matches

Tags: php, sql-order-by, wordpress

I have a custom `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'resource',
 'tax_query' => array(
   array(
      'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'tax_term'
   ),
 ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This returns all resources in the `tax_term` "mytax" taxonomy. What I would like to do, though, **is further sort those terms by the presence of a string** (probably the term itself) so that any posts with `tax_term` in their title or possibly their `post_content` are shown first.

I am not sure about the best way to go about doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at [WP_Query's Search parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) to get you started. See if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that will return ONLY posts with the keyword defined. I had thought about that, but I need all posts from the original query with a custom sorting of word matches. Thanks though.

Comment: You want to sort posts by taxonomy? Pretty sure you can't do that, but you can sort by title or date in ascending or descending order. You're already showing posts that have said taxonomy first, because your query only returns said taxonomy posts. Unless your real query is more complicated of course. 

That said, you're better off using raw sql queries, or multiple wp_queries and combining the results. You could always put the results in an array, and use something to sort them. Cache and transients will probably forgive you that slow query, if you happen to create one.

Comment: No I don't want to sort necessarily by taxonomy. I want to be able to sort by any string or word I give it. It just happens to be the taxonomy this time. So for example I want all resources in the 'test' taxonomy, but I'd like the resources whose title contains the word 'free' to be shown first.